# How to search JSON element using SwiftyJSON in Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift3, swifty-json

I search around here and little example to show how to search a json element in SwiftyJSON. I have below json structure, can anyone tech me? thanks.

```js
var jsonData = {
      "css":[
         {
            "path": "style.css",
            "updated": "12432"
         },
         {
            "path": "base.css",
            "updated": "34627"
         }
      ],
      "html":[
         {
            "path": "home.htm",
            "updated": "3223"
         },
         {
            "path": "about",
            "updated": "3987"
         }
      ]
    }
```

I want to search the "html" -> "home.htm" row. How to make use of filter method for it.

I got example like this for simple json structure, but in my case I have no idea.

```js
{
    countryid : "1"
    name : "New York"
},
{
    countryid : "2"
    name : "Sydeny"
}

if let array = arrCountry.arrayObject as? [[String:String]],
   foundItem = array.filter({ $0["name"] == "def"}).first {
   print(foundItem)
}
```

Comment: You want to search in the JSON you provided for the values `html` and then `home.htm` ? So you are looking to get the `updated` value ?

Comment: Yes, I want a quick seach to "home.htm" and get the "updated" value. It is because I have another json data same structure for compare this element exist and compare "updated" value

Answer (score 1):

```
let updated = json["html"].array?.filter { $0["path"].string == "home.htm" }.first?["updated"].string
print(updated)

// OR

for subJson in json["html"].arrayValue where subJson["path"].stringValue == "home.htm" {
    let updated  = subJson["updated"].stringValue
    print(updated)
}
```